# Should I create a Bootcamp partition (even if i plan on using parallels)?

Tags: bootcamp, parallels-desktop

I just got a mac and i need to use windows sometimes.  I plan on buying parallels.  Someone mentioned that even though i plan on using parallels (so i don't need to reboot to run windows) that I should still do a bootcamp partition and then call up that partition from parallels.

Does this make sense?  I don't understand the benefit of why I would do this versus just using parallels by itself (without bootcamp partition)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't thinks so. I've been using VMWare (same way of working as Parallels) for years now without a partition and I've never suffered any issues.

When using virtualisation software without a partition, the software creates a dynamic partition which will grow depending on your needs. So basically, it's the same. Only the dynamic partition is a virtual one.

So, in my opinion, there is no need to waste a predefined partition on your Macintosh HD. Just let the software do it's job and go with the dynamic partition.

Comment: I think this question relates to Parallels' ability to virtualize a boot camp partition, allowing you to access same copy of windows by both fully running under boot camp, AND being able to run it in a VM

Comment: @XAleXOwnZX - it sounds like you are saying there is an advantage because then you can use Windows natively if you want.  Are there any benefits to that (performance?, etc?)

Comment: Yes, the graphics card emulated by Parallel's is kinda sketchy. You can never commit 100% of your system resources to a virtualized OS, so running boot camp lets you (for example) play games with 100% of ur mac's ram and video memory, and without OS X taking up any of it.

Comment: @XaleXOwnZX, but the question is about using a physical partition or not with his Parallels. Not choosing between Parallels and Bootcamp.

Comment: You must have misunderstood me. Parallels can run off of a BOOTCAMP partition, virtualizing Windows as if it was in a parallel's virtual image, but also allowing you to boot into Windows directly if you want extra performance.

Comment: http://download.parallels.com/desktop/v6/docs/en/Parallels_Desktop_Users_Guide/23112.htm Read that if u still don't get me